# Ajax mvc api: bad request when sending viewmodel

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with Ajax to send a request to my web api, written in c#.
I am sending a viewmodel, but I receive a bad request error. 
This is my code:

```
[HttpPut]
/*api controller*/
public IHttpActionResult UpdateCursoProfesor(int CourseId, CourseViewModel ViewModel)
{
/*Do something*/
return Ok(result);
}
```

this is my viewmodel:

```
public class CursoViewModel
{
[MaxLength(125)]
public string Tittle{ get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my ajax

```
 function GeneralPost(CursoDto) {

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "http://localhost:59245/api/ProfesorCurso?CourseId=123",
                type: "Put",
                dataType:'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({

                    Tittle: 'My tittle',
                    Description: 'I am describing yea'
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert ('we did it!')
                },
                error: function (msg) { alert('bad bad'); }
            });
        }
```

When I do not include the  "data" in the ajax request, I can reach my api controller, but when I include data, there is an exception:
http://localhost:59245/api/ProfesorCurso?CourseId=400 bad request

Any hint about what I am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Check the request headers, specifically the Content-Type. Bad Request is often returned when the headers doesn't match the content format.

Answer (score 0):

this `CourseId` parameter type is `Guid`.  Action link CourseId parameter isn't `Guid     "http://localhost:59245/api/ProfesorCurso?CourseId=123",`

make the `ActionResult` method parameter `type` `int` or send correct `Guid` value `view` to `controller`

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateCursoProfesor(int CourseId, CourseViewModel ViewModel)
{
/*Do something*/
return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks. I have changed as you mentioned, but the error is still there. When I do not include the data, it passes the request to the api controller,but the Viewmodel object in Api is empty. However when I include data, there is a 400 error

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing looks incorrect

First, the url must include the controller AND action, unless you follow REST prionciples which obviously you are not.

Assuming your controller is called ProfesorCursoController then your url should be something like this:

http://localhost:59245/api/ProfesorCurso/UpdateCursoProfesor

Now, because you issue a PUT request, your data should be in the body of the request not in the URL.

I'd make sure your ViewModel contains the courseID as well and parse it together with Tittle and Description.

Your controller would look something like this:

```
[HttpPut]
/*api controller*/
public IHttpActionResult UpdateCursoProfesor([FromBody] CourseViewModel ViewModel)
{
/*Do something*/
return Ok(result);
}
```

your javascript:

```
function GeneralPost(CursoDto) {

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: "http://localhost:59245/api/ProfesorCurso/UpdateCursoProfesor",
                type: "PUT",
                dataType:'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    CourseID : some GUID not int!
                    Tittle: 'My tittle',
                    Description: 'I am describing yea'
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert ('we did it!')
                },
                error: function (msg) { alert('bad bad'); }
            });
        }
```

and finally your ViewModel:

```
public class CourseViewModel 
{
     public Guid CourseID { get;set; }
     public string Tittle { get;set; } 
     public string Description { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, unfortunately, I arrive to the same issue, when I do not include the data:json..... , the put request goes through the controller, and the viewmodel object parameter is empty. But when I use this aproach I have the bad request error, and get the alert  "bad Bad"